# Clear the Session Store

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, session, mongoose

I am currently developing a Node.js application. I am using connect-mongo with Express to handle my session store. I am also using Mongoose for other database operations.

However, when I re-start my server in order to test new functionality, the old session data is still there. This is leading to data inconsistencies and some tricky bugs.

So when the server first starts up, I would like to be able to clear out all data from the sessions collection in my Mongo database.

I know that, using Mongoose, I can do something like this to clear out a collection:

```
User.remove({}, function (error) {
  console.log('Emptied user collection')
});
```

However, I don't know how I can get a reference to a collection without declaring its schema.

Does anyone know how I can make this work? Or is there some entirely different approach I should be taking to handle all of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I think I found some solutions to my problem.

It is actually quite simple to get a reference to a collection without declaring its schema. Not sure how I hadn't found this in my research before I asked this question... So here is the complete solution to what I had been asking about:

```
mongoose.connection.db.collection('sessions', function (error, collection) {
  if (error) {
    console.error('Problem retrieving sessions collection:', error);
  } else {
    collection.remove({}, function (error) {
      if (error) {
        console.error('Problem emptying sessions collection:', error);
      } else {
        console.log('Emptied sessions collection');
      }
    });
  }
});
```

However, in my case, I actually wanted to delete all data from the database, and was trying to do this one collection at a time (because I knew how to clear out a collection). Instead, I just needed to use [`db.dropDatabase()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.dropDatabase/).